# Django - not showing my var in template

Tags: python, django

I'm starting in Django.

I'm trying to pass to my template my `var` to be shown in my browser but not working.

here's my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from preguntasyrespuestas.models import Pregunta
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    string = 'hi world'
    return render_to_response('test/index.html',
                                {'string': string})
```

here's my urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from preguntasyrespuestas.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
]
```

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Preguntas </title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>{{ string }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Basicaly I want to show what's in `string` in my template. but not working..

My error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in django_examples.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^$ [name='index']

The current URL, test/index.html, didn't match any of these.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You should not add `test/index.html` at the end of your url in the browser, just something like http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and make sure that `templates/test/index.html` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Django's url routing uses regular expressions to match routes.

```
url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
```

In this case you have just a single valid route, which is the empty string `r'^$'`. So you can only get a response by visiting for example `http://localhost:8000`. All other urls will fail.

Django's url routing is completely independent from where your template files are located on your file system. Therefore `http://localhost/test/index.html` will not be valid, even though there is a template file with that name.

You could make a catch-all route by using this pattern that will match any url path.

```
url(r'', index, name='index'),
```